# Matrix reconstruction puzzle

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, permutations, singular-values

Say a reconstruction of matrix $A$ is $A'$  and it's defined as
$$
A' = PDP^TA
$$
where $P$ is an orthogonal matrix, $D$ is a diagonal binary (1 or 0) matrix. In a trivial case, when all diagonal elements are 1, we have a perfect reconstruction ($A'=A$).

Now we constrain the number of 1's in the diagonal entries of $D$ to, say, $n$. How do I find the best $D$ s.t. $\operatorname{Tr}(D)=n$ that would minimize $\lVert A-A'\rVert$? $P$ and $A$ are fixed.

I think I need to inspect the singular vectors of $A$, but I am not sure what to do exactly. I think the 1's in $D$ should indicate columns of $P$ that best align with the column space of $A$, but what how do I determine the "best" alignment?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EDIT: as OP confirm that they need the Frobenius norm, this should be a complete solution for that case]

Since that norm is orthogonally invariant,
$$
\|A - A'\| = \|P^T(A-A')\| = \|P^TA - DP^TA\| = \|(I-D)P^TA\|,
$$
so essentially the question becomes "you are allowed to zero out $n$ rows of $B= P^TA$; which choice leaves you with the minimum norm"? This looks like a simpler reformulation.

If the norm is the Frobenius norm, then the answer is choosing the $n$ rows with the largest norm; I suspect that the same holds also for the 2-norm, but this is not immediate and sometimes these kinds of problems have a different solution when one switches norm.

Comment: I see. I meant Frobenius norm. So I need to permute the rows/columns of $D$ until I can maximize $||DB||$. Since the extreme points of Birkhoff polytope (polytope of doubly stochastic matrices) are permutation matrices, I can do linear programming to find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Stupid question: it intuitively makes sense to find maximum solution, but how does minimizing $||DP^TA-P^TA||$ becomes maximizing $||DP^TA||$?

Comment: @ChanwooChun Sorry, I had switched $D$ and $I-D$ in my head at some point; now it should be fixed (and clearer). Anyhow, you do not need to do any linear programming; just compute the norm of each row of $B$, find the largest $n$ norms, and put ones in the corresponding rows of $D$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I think there are still some typos though. Thanks again!

Comment: Rechecked, thanks. Feel free to edit the answer if you spot more typos.